# Set Title for ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: iphone

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to change the title of the navigation bar for a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. I do not want to use a UILabel as in

[Customizing Title in the NavigationBar for a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954891/customizing-title-in-the-navigationbar-for-a-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller)

Just want to know if there is legal way that guarantees the app not being rejected.

Answer (score 0):

in your viewDidLoad put this line:

```
[picker.topViewController setTitle:@"Contacts"];
```

where picker is from type (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)

Comment: in swift it crashes because topViewController is nil, in obj-c does nothing for the same reason